# Should I put some glue in the pre drilled hole before installing an eye screw?

Tags: wood, bolts

Going to put in some eye screws under the deck for a swing.

Should I add some glue in the predrill for extra durability?

I've also read vaseline is good for easier installation, but that's opposite of what I'm asking...

Comment: vaseline is good after the install of the eyebolts to avoid corrosion and squeaks

Comment: You want to place a large amount of consideration on the safety margin of the eye screw when used in a swing application. Or any vertical hanging application for that matter!! Look carefully at the load ratings of the screws used. Also consider using a larger diameter and longer thread length to get more engagement with the wood. Also be aware that when using a eye screw there is an ideal size to pre-drill into the wood - not too large and not too small. Installing with too small or no pre-drill will tend to split the wood resulting in a much lower strength assembly than with the ideal hole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using an eye bolt or an eye screw?
[image: Eye bolt] **OR**         [image: Eye screw]

For an eye screw, glue won't do much and is not needed. (Although some glues may act as a lubricant when you first screw-in the eye-screw.)  Use bar soap or beeswax as a lubricant.

For an eye bolt, especially if you want it to be able to pivot, use appropriate washers, plus **two** nuts with a lock-washer in between.  For extra reliability use [*Loctite*](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/t_lkr_blue/overview/Loctite-Threadlocker-Blue-242.htm), not glue, where the nuts and eye-bolt meet.

If you don't need/want pivoting action, then one nut may suffice, but *Loctite* is even more important because such eye-bolts always loosen their compressive grip on the wood over time.

Comment: it is actually an eye screw vertically going into a vertical 2x6.  I will be adding a chain connector, and then the swing chain.  I was just wondering if the glue would give even just a bit more stability.

Comment: If the glue bonds both wood and metal, and it makes you feel better, go ahead and use it.  In my experience, it is not necessary though.